# AngularJS filter does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular 1.x in my project and I want to create a filter, I know how to do it but it does not work, it does not throw any console error either.

This is my js code:

```
var myAPP = angular.module("myAPP",[]);

myAPP.filter("miFilter",function(){
    return function(input){
      return input.replace("normal","400x400");
    };
});
```

and in my html file I use this:

```
<img src="{{url | miFilter}}" />
```

Comment: your filter works (http://plnkr.co/edit/oSLyBQX461npbuQR6Nu7?p=preview), i would suspect that this is a problem with `$scope.url` being undefined or not being set by its controller

Comment: the problem was to use src and not ng-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `src`. Use `ng-src` instead.

From the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a `src` attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The `ngSrc` directive solves this problem.

Comment: Lo siento llevo tiempo consultado esta web, pero es la primera que vez que publico una pregunta y no se muy bien como va este sitio :)

Comment: @Keite — no hay problema, y bienvenido a stackoverflow! éste es el mejor sitio del mundo... TIP: aquí puedes aprender mucho si usas *tags* en la búsqueda y filtras artículos por votos/popularidad...

Comment: Okey, Gracias por el consejo y la bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as a reference and change according to your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg';
        }).filter("miFilter",function(){
            return function(input){
              return input.replace("normal","400x400");
            };
        });;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
        <img ng-src="{{url | miFilter}}" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Keite great. but this will be helpful for someone else :)